# Sending email with Sendgrid not recommended Gmail

Tags: validation, email, sendgrid

I need to setup a sender identity on sendgrip.com but before i create them, is say the ".gmail" extension is not recommended.

I learn is because the DMARC and i understand, but is say gmail, outlook, yahoo, aol and a lot other none write have a DMARC.

So my question what i need to use ?? Or best question what is the best extension in this case ?
(https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/dmarc/)
Thanks a lot for you help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [How DMARC Applies to a Sender Identity](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/dmarc/#how-dmarc-applies-to-a-sender-identity), email service providers like Sendgrid assume that you have your own registered domain such as raphaelr.com and that you have access to the [DNS records](https://sendgrid.com/docs/glossary/dns/) for that domain.

You can then setup Domain Authentication by creating the appropriate CNAME DNS records:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication/